# why we need to use both Resource and SlingHttpServletRequest in AEM sling models

Tags: java, adobe, aem

@Model(adaptables = {Resource.class, SlingHttpServletRequest.class}, defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
public class LearningPanelModel {

```
@Inject
private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;

//OR
@Inject @Source("sling-object")
private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;

//OR
@SlingObject
private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;

//OR
@ScriptVariable
private ResourceResolver resolver;
```

}

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking which way you should be obtaining the resource resolver?

Comment: I strongly recommend using either one of it. Using both could cause very strange behaviors, aka bugs. See my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68847287/8131885